# Best way to schedule a copy command in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data staged in azure blob storage.
According to snowflake documentation, I am confused, whether I should use create task feature of snowflake with below sql query :

```
 copy into table_name from azure_stage_name file format = xyz
```

Or should I use snowpipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to trigger data ingestion when a new file arrives? In this case, Snowpipe would be the right choice.

If you want to ingest the files on a fixed frequency such as daily/hourly etc, then a task would be enough.

If this is a one-time data load, then you can directly run the COPY command.

Answer (score -1):

Copy INTO is probably easier and more flexible than auto-ingest.

Comment: Thanks @Gokhan Atil , Task would be the right choice as the frequency is daily at fixed hours. Thanks for clarifying